# When using SWRevealViewController, can I keep the status bar stable?

Tags: ios, swift, slider, swrevealviewcontroller

I used SWRevealViewController class to implement a slide bar. The image below shows what the top of the screen looks like. As you can see, the status bar on the top slid together.

[image]

What I'd like to do is as following. It is the design I was given, which I should keep the status bar stable without sliding. Is it possible for me to do this with the SWRevealViewController class?

[image]